# Array function is not a function

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js

I want to add a function to an Array. It is an Express, Node.js Server. But that should not be the point.

I added the following Function. I know its not ready (that's not the point)

```
File: users.cache.js

// Thats my Array
let Users = []



  Users.findOne = function (user) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (typeof user === 'string') {
      for (let i = 0; i < Users.length; ++i) {
        if (Users[i].username === user) {
          resolve(Users[i])
        }
      }
    } else if (typeof user === 'number') {
      for (let i = 0; i < Users.length; ++i) {
        if (Users[i].id === user) {
          resolve(Users[i])
        }
      }
    } else {
      reject('Invalid Data Type')
    }
  })
}

 module.exports = {   
  Users    
}
```

I tried to call the Function in another file.
Lets name the file: users.service.js

```
import usersCache from './users.cache'



  selectUser(req, res) {


        usersCache.Users.findOne(req.params.username).then((userData) => { }

}
```

If I try to execute the function I get the following Error.

TypeError: _users4.default.Users.findOne is not a function

Can someone explain my fault? and how to fix it.

Thanks :)

Comment: does `_users4.default` mean anything to you?

Comment: This is really ugly, why not just export an object like so: `{findOne: function(....) {}}`

Comment: @Bravo No, not really.

Comment: @Ele I´m learning js, could be that my style is not best

Comment: well, your code as is works just fine

Comment: I can't reproduce it https://codesandbox.io/s/pxkqwo8km I might have trimmed something essential away but I don't think I did

Comment: hmm. so it must be a problem @ my side. thanks for your quick help. I will continue searching the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so i found the Solution. The error was a circular dependency which causes the users4_ error message. Resolving the circular depency solves the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Update your module exports block.
Change it to from

```
module.exports = {   
 Users    
}
```

TO

```
module.exports = {   
  Users:Users    
}
```

module.exports is a object - with key value pairs - the users you put in your code is not referring to the users function in your code - but is simply a property of module.exports object - assign your Users object to users property - this should work.

Comment: That's a standard shorthand to declare a property equal to the value of a variable with the same name

Comment: OP's problem isn't a `SyntaxError`. He's using arrow functions already, so `module.exports = {   
 Users    
}` surely isn't a problem either.